# .NET CORE 3 хостинг на IIS. Обеспечение "параллельной" обработки входящих запросов

Tags: iis-10, .net-core-3.0-webapi

Есть проект WebAPI на платформе .NET Core 3.

У меня цель обеспечить "параллельность" обработки запросов средствами IIS.

Иными словами, можно ли заставить IIS поднимать для каждого запроса к API отдельный инстанс приложения ?

Знаю, что раньше в ASP.NET это работало посредством IIS ApplicationPool.

Подскажите , как это работает в случае .NET Core ?

И влияет ли на это тип модели хостинга: InProcess или OutOfProcess ?

Спасибо!

Comment: У меня цель обеспечить "параллельность" обработки запросов средствами IIS. - не понятно а сейчас там последовательное?

Comment: У вас веб служба. каждый метод изолирован все и так сделано чтобы обрабатывать параллельно